Django: object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
my models.py is Like this:
from django.db import models


class Form(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField()
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    # Magic Method
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name}{self.last_name}"


My forms.py is:
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    date = forms.DateField()
    occupation = forms.CharField(max_length=80)

And my views.py is:
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm
from .models import Form

def index(request):
    # To fetch data from webpage
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data["fname"]
            last_name = form.cleaned_data["lname"]
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            date = form.cleaned_data["date"]
            occupation = form.cleaned_data["occupation"]
            print(first_name)
            # To store in database
            Form.objects.create(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email,
                                date=date, occupation=occupation)
    return render(request, "index.html")


And I am getting the following error:
'ContactForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
In 'views.py' -- "if form.is_validate()" is returning "False"..and the following code is not executing.
Here is the html:
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class="mt-4 mb-4">Job Application Form</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <label for="date">Available start date:</label><br>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" id="date" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <label>Current Occupation:</label><br>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical" id="occupation">
            <input class="btn-check form-control" type="radio" name="occupation" id="employed" value="employed" required>
            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="employed">Employed</label>

            <input class="btn-check form-control" type="radio" name="occupation" id="un_employed" value="un_employed" required>
            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="un_employed">Unemployed</label>

            <input class="btn-check form-control" type="radio" name="occupation" id="self_employed" value="self_employed" required>
            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="self_employed">Self-Employed</label>
            
            <input class="btn-check form-control" type="radio" name="occupation" id="student" value="student" required>
            <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="student">Student</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button><br><br>
    
        {% if messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {% for message in messages %}
        {{message}}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

</form>
{% endblock %}


You forgot to post your form.

My bad, updates now!!

Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

tbh is not showing any error, but its not fetching any data from the webpage ex: first_name..and when I printed "if form.is_validate()" it is returning "False"

Can you share the HTML of the form? Likely it thus means the data is not valid, as well as the data you have entered?

html code has been shared

Even If your data does not validate, there will still be a cleaned_data dictionary and the cleaned_data dictionary contains only the valid fields.

so what to do ?

Explain this statement for clarity. And why did you write this? "if form.is_valid?ate" is returning "False"..and the following code is not executing.

becuz, if it returns False, the following code doesn't work?

The issue seems to be with the form field names in your HTML not matching the field names in your Django form. In your HTML form, you're using fname and lname, but in your Django form, you're using first_name and last_name.
You need to adjust your HTML form to match the field names in your Django form.
Try this:
<div class="form-group mb-4">
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fname" name="first_name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-4">
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" id="lname" required>
</div>


nope its not working

@str_name are you getting the same error?
